# Replace string or var in text template based on user input (form)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm not sure how to accomplish this and if HTML and JS are the best solutions for this or if PHP would make more sense. So I have a template (a JSON-LD script) where I want to replace several strings based on user input on a web page and then output the modified template. Instead of replacing strings, it would be fine to use variables as well.

Let's say this is my template:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Foo",
  "name": "Bar"
}
</script>
```

I'd now want to have a web page with input fields for values for both `Foo` and `Bar` and a submit/generate button.

On submit, `Foo` and `Bar` would then be replaced with the user input, and the whole script would be put out with `Foo` and `Bar` replaced within `<pre>` tags for the user to copy.

What would be the best approach to this, and does anyone happen to have an example?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't edit JSON manually. Create an array or an object and then encode that into JSON (whether it's in PHP or JS, doesn't matter, the principle is the same).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a form that generates formatted JSON data, you could add a submission handler to the form.

When the user submits the form, spread the form values on a default object and pass it into a template generator function.

```js
const generateJsonLinkedDataTemplate = (data) =>
  `<script type="application/ld+json">
${JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}
<\/script>`;

const defaultLinkedDataTemplateData = {
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": null,
  "name": null
};

const output = document.querySelector('.output');

const generate = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const { type, name } = e.target.elements;
  output.value = generateJsonLinkedDataTemplate({
    ...defaultLinkedDataTemplateData,
    '@type': type.value,
    name: name.value
  });
};

document.forms['template-generator'].addEventListener('submit', generate);
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
 
.vertical-form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 6em 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 0.25em;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.output {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<form name="template-generator" class="vertical-form">
  <label>Type</label>
  <input type="text" name="type" value="Foo" />
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" value="Bar" />
  <span></span>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<textarea class="output"></textarea>
```